# Axon Event Handler not executing on a different microservice

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I'm using CQRS with axon Framework in a project,and I'm using Kafka like evnt bus and MongoDB like event store
I have two Microservices, One for the Command Side and the Other for Query Side.
In the Query side I'm try using MySQL database for storing aggregates events, but the eventHandler does not work and I don Know why.

Command Microservice
[image]

Query Microservice
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello @abdogh, do the two microservices use the same mongoDB url? If so, can you share your event processor and configuration code? If we are to debug this we need more information :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the configuration of the event handler? Or maybe some kind of error you are getting? Could be a lot of things. Might be because you use MySQL and Spring Boot, it actually trying to use MySQL as event store, and not MongoDB.

Comment: I add more Infos, and there is no error.
I receive the event in Kafka but I do not receive it in the event handler